# How to grab #access_token on the url on instagram api

Tags: html, instagram-api

I request a instagram api access token and it return and url with the token ,something like that `http://localhost/pruebainst/pruebas.php#access_token=MY_TOKEN`.
My question is how I can get this token of the url to store it on a variable to use it?It is not on $_GET OR $_POST.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `php` or other server-side code to get hash fragment in URL. You have to use `javascript`

```
var access_token = window.location.hash.split('access_token=')[1];
```